# Writing Powershell Pester Test to check output contains multiple values

Tags: azure, powershell, unit-testing, pester

I'm trying to check the permissions for an app registration in Azure and running

```
(Get-AzRoleAssignment -ObjectId $objectId).RoleDefinitionName
```

It returns multiple values, e.g "Owner, Contributor, Reader, KeyVault Secret User" etc.

I'm trying to write a Pester test to ensure it has either two values, or one.

As an example, $objectId should **contain** "Contributor" **and** KeyVault Secret User, **OR**, "Owner". So the test is happy as long as it has 'Owner', or 'Contributor/KeyVault Secret User'. Just to note, the test should still pass if it has all 3.

I have the below so far but can't seem to get this working from what I've found online.

```
BeforeALL {
    
    $objectId = "<App-Reg-Object-Id>"
    $RoleDefName = Get-AzRoleAssignment -ObjectId $objectId
}

Describe "Permissions Role Definition Checks" {


    It "Checked the App Reg and it has the correct permissions" {
        if ($RoleDefName.RoleDefinitionName | Should -Contain 'Owner')
        {
            Write-Host "Owner permission successfully found"
        }
        else {
            $RoleDefName.RoleDefinitionName | Should -Contain 'Contributor'|'User Access Administrator'
        }
    }
}
    
}
```

Any help would be greatly appreciated

****EDIT****

This is now working with the help of Mark Wraggs' comment! I had to move the logic to the left of the Should, with a ForEach for the multiple roles. Below is how I got this working.

```
Describe "Permissions Role Definition Checks" {

    It "Checked the App Reg and it has the correct permissions" -ForEach 'User Access Administrator','Contributor' {
        $RoleDefName.RoleDefinitionName -Contains 'Owner' -Or $RoleDefName.RoleDefinitionName -Contains $_ | Should -Be $true

    }
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For this assertion, you need to do:

```
$RoleDefName.RoleDefinitionName | Should -Contain 'Contributor','User Access Administrator'
```

But because your scenario is a bit complex (where you want to check for two different results) it might be better to move the logic to the left of the `Should`. For example:

```
$RoleDefName.RoleDefinitionName -Contains 'Owner' -Or $RoleDefName.RoleDefinitionName -Contains 'Contributor','User Access Administrator' | Should -Be $true
```

Comment: Thank you for the reply Mark. I've tried the first assertation but unfortunately this does not work. Using the comma between the two roles throws an error message where it's expecting the whole collection. Error message below: 

Expected @('Contributor','User Access Administrator') to be found in collection @('Owner', 'User Access Administrator', 'Contributor', 'Reader', 'Key Vault Contributor'), but it was not found.

Comment: I managed to figure this out using a ForEach, along with the second Assertation you provided and it worked. Thank you so much Mark!!!! I have updated my original post to provide the fix